# Beamer and table of contents

Tags: beamer

I have a problem in beamer (warsaw) each time I create a new section and compile it a slide containing the table of contents is created before it; That slide contains the table of contents with the other sections invisible but this section is visible.
How to remove the slide that appears containing the table of contents before each new frame created in beamer ?

Comment: This is not the default behaviour, so there is something in your code activating it. I don't know `beamer` well enough to guess what that might be, but if you make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) demonstrating it, I'll probably be able to find out. Of course, if you make a proper MWE you might find out yourself exactly what it is.

Comment: After browsing the `beamer` manual a bit, I'm guessing you have a `\AtBeginSection{ \begin{frame} \tableofcontents[currentsection] \end{frame} }` (or similar) somewhere. But without seeing some code that is just guessing.

Comment: yes that's true i have used \AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Layout}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
} I have putted this code to make the bar of the contents appear on each slide. The other commands are just normal \section and \subsection

Comment: oh I removed that command and it worked ! thanks @TorbjørnT.

Comment: What that code does is that `At` the `Begin`ing of every `Subsection`, it inserts `\begin{frame}  \tableofcontents[...] \end{frame}`, thus giving you those extra frames.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. Yes exactly!